# Ruby wrapper over a existing C library

Tags: ruby

I want write a ruby wrapper for a existing C library (.so files). Can anyone point me to books/websites that can get me started with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [FFI gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/ffi).

Answer (score 3):

You have several options:

- [swig](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Ruby.html) / [hand written C
  extension](http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to-create-a-ruby-extension-in-c-in-under-5-minutes-100.html) but those won't be
  usable in other VM than MRI (won't
  work in jruby, rubinius...)
- [FFI](http://github.com/ffi/ffi) which will be usable on
  other VM. example [here](http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-ffi-library-calling-external-libraries-now-easier-1293.html)